# MySQL self join but in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

| date | sku | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/12 | 123 | note |
| 11/13 | 123 | note |
| 11/12 | 456 | note |
| 11/13 | 456 | note |
| 11/12 | 789 | note |
| 11/13 | 789 | note |

(Note is random)
And I want the result to return this:

| date | sku | note | sku | note | sku | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/12 | 123 | note | 456 | note | 789 | note |
| 11/13 | 123 | note | 456 | note | 789 | note |

I tried self join

```
select * from schedules a, schedules b 
where a.date = b.date;
```

but this is what I got:

| date | sku | note | sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/12 | 123 | note | 456 |
| 11/12 | 123 | note | 789 |
| 11/13 | 123 | note | 456 |
| 11/13 | 123 | note | 789 |

Comment: please, could you provide more information about why you need to do self-join ?

Comment: which version of mysql?

Comment: Search for mysql pivot - this is such a common question there's lots to be found.

Comment: @LukStorms version 8.0.18

Comment: @Faesal I don't have to use self-join, but that is just what I found so I thought it could be done using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate a row_number, then pivot.

```
select `date`
, max(case when rn = 1 then sku end) as sku1
, max(case when rn = 1 then note end) as note1
, max(case when rn = 2 then sku end) as sku2
, max(case when rn = 2 then note end) as note2
, max(case when rn = 3 then sku end) as sku3
, max(case when rn = 3 then note end) as note3
from
(
    select `date`, sku, note
    , row_number() over (partition by `date` order by sku) as rn
    from schedules 
) q
where rn <= 3
group by `date`
order by `date`
```